# How to create new columns in R every time a given value appears?

Tags: r

I have a question regarding creating new columns if a certain value appears in an existing row.

```
N=5
T=5
time<-rep(1:T, times=N)
id<- rep(1:N,each=T)
dummy<- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(id, time, dummy)

   id time dummy
1   1    1     0
2   1    2     0
3   1    3     1
4   1    4     1
5   1    5     0
6   2    1     0
7   2    2     0
8   2    3     1
9   2    4     0
10  2    5     0
11  3    1     0
12  3    2     1
13  3    3     0
14  3    4     1
15  3    5     0
16  4    1     0
17  4    2     0
18  4    3     0
19  4    4     0
20  4    5     0
21  5    1     1
22  5    2     0
23  5    3     0
24  5    4     1
25  5    5     0
```

In this case we have some cross-sections in which more than one 1 appears. Now I try to create a new dummy variable/column for each additional 1. After that, for each dummy, the rows for each cross-section should also be filled with a 1 after the first 1 appears. I can fill the rows by using group_by(id) and the cummax function on each column. But how do I get new variables without going through every cross-section manually? So I want to achieve the following:

```
   id time dummy dummy2
1   1    1     0      0
2   1    2     0      0
3   1    3     1      0
4   1    4     1      1
5   1    5     1      1
6   2    1     0      0
7   2    2     0      0
8   2    3     1      0
9   2    4     1      0
10  2    5     1      0
11  3    1     0      0
12  3    2     1      0
13  3    3     1      0
14  3    4     1      1
15  3    5     1      1
16  4    1     0      0
17  4    2     0      0
18  4    3     0      0
19  4    4     0      0
20  4    5     0      0
21  5    1     1      0
22  5    2     1      0
23  5    3     1      0
24  5    4     1      1
25  5    5     1      1
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: `as.data.frame(cbind(.))` is **terrible!** I will edit.

Comment: Do not understand what you mean. Why is `dummy` different in each data frame? Not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cummax` and you would need `cumsum` to create `dummy2`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(dummy1 = cummax(dummy), # don't alter 'dummy' here we need it in the next line
         dummy2 = cummax(cumsum(dummy) == 2)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() # needed only to display the entire result
#   id time dummy dummy1 dummy2
#1   1    1     0      0      0
#2   1    2     0      0      0
#3   1    3     1      1      0
#4   1    4     1      1      1
#5   1    5     0      1      1
#6   2    1     0      0      0
#7   2    2     0      0      0
#8   2    3     1      1      0
#9   2    4     0      1      0
#10  2    5     0      1      0
#11  3    1     0      0      0
#12  3    2     1      1      0
#13  3    3     0      1      0
#14  3    4     1      1      1
#15  3    5     0      1      1
#16  4    1     0      0      0
#17  4    2     0      0      0
#18  4    3     0      0      0
#19  4    4     0      0      0
#20  4    5     0      0      0
#21  5    1     1      1      0
#22  5    2     0      1      0
#23  5    3     0      1      0
#24  5    4     1      1      1
#25  5    5     0      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks again! :) This is exactly what I was looking for!